# Is it possible to configure DHCP on a router or UTM firewall for the multiple VLANs on L3 Switch?

Tags: cisco, router, vlan, firewall, dhcp

I'm working on expanding our office network to accommodate more users/devices. Currently we have the DHCP configured on a UTM firewall(cyberoam ing50) device(cum router) providing IP addresses for Cisco WLC, Cisco L3 Switch(PoE), Cisco Aironet Access Points and for all other clients. I'm planning for configuring some VLANs on L3 Switch to isolate wireless, wired and cctv traffic.

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to configure DHCP on router/UTM firewall to provide IP addresses for clients on different VLANs, or I should DHCP pool on the Switch itself for the VLANs?. I have no much experience with VLANs, any help is appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data sheet for that device claims "*Multiple DHCP Servers support, DHCP relay*." That means that it should do what you want. You need to set up a DHCP scope on it for each VLAN, then you need to set up the DHCP relay (`ip helper-address`) on the layer-3 SVIs of your Cisco layer-3 switch.